# Дефект вёрстки на вкладке Активность в личном профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

[image: Дефект вёрстки на вкладке Активность в личном профиле]

Кнопка `Узнать подробнее >` не помещается по ширине и смещена вниз.
Скриншот с моей личной страницы профиля.
Браузер Firefox 45.0.2 / Chrome 51.0.2704.103

Comment: Chrome 52.0.2743.82 m (64-bit) Аналогично